# Django cache framework. What is the difference between TIMEOUT and CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS?

Tags: django, django-cache

I have been setting up caching in Django using a database cache. There are two settings TIMEOUT and CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS that control how long a page is cached for. What is the difference between these two settings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed the respective documentation does not adequately explain the differences.

The first option, `CACHES`: `TIMEOUT` is introduced in [Django cache framework, Cache arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/). It is the default expiration time that is used in functions such as `cache.set()`, if none else is provided. This is later documented in the [low-level cache API usage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#basic-usage).

The latter, `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS` is introduced in [Django cache framework, The per-site cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache). Therefore it might be safe to assume that it is the default expiration time for all pages, as if the `@cache_page(settings.CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS)` would have been used on a [per-view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache) basis.

Comment: `TIMEOUT` only affects server-side caching, whereas `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS` affects both client-side and server-side caching. Am I correct?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same question and the existing answers still didn't clear it up for me. So I decided to dive into the source code. Yay for open source!

[`CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS) gets used by the `UpdateCacheMiddleware` middleware. It sets the `Cache-Control` (`max-age`) header to the value of `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS` if the view didn't already set it, affecting the client-side cache. Here's the code:

```
    self.cache_timeout = settings.CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS
    # ...
    timeout = get_max_age(response)
    if timeout is None:
        timeout = self.cache_timeout
    patch_response_headers(response, timeout)
```

(Note that I'm cutting out some code and edge-corners to make this quicker to read, you can read [the full source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9356f63a99957f01c14a9788617428a172a29fcb/django/middleware/cache.py#L91) code yourself of course.)

It also saves the response in the server-side cache, using the same timeout value which originates from `MIDDLEWARE_CACHE_SECONDS`, overriding the `TIMEOUT` setting if it had been set: ([context](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9356f63a99957f01c14a9788617428a172a29fcb/django/middleware/cache.py#L98))

```
    if timeout:
        cache_key = learn_cache_key(request, response, timeout, self.key_prefix, cache=self.cache)
        self.cache.set(cache_key, response, timeout)
```

The middleware `FetchFromCacheMiddleware` goes with `UpdateCacheMiddleware`, and it uses the server-side cache values set by the latter, so it is indirectly affected by `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS`.

The alternative middleware `CacheMiddleware` also uses `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS`. This shouldn't affect you unless you're using `CacheMiddleware`.

So what's the point of the `TIMEOUT` setting? I suppose it's the default value that's used if you're writing to the cache directly, but it isn't used by the previously mentioned middleware. For example:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set('my_key', 'my_value') # uses TIMEOUT value as default
```

Comment: sorry, but what is the default timeout here?
for example
`cache.set("my_key", ''my_value", timeout=none)` this code means that data in cache will stay for unlimited time?

Comment: @KaramQusai The default timeout for `cache.set` is the [`TIMEOUT` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#timeout).

Answer (score -2):

According to http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter15.html, TIMEOUT is the timeout for connecting to the cache backend and CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS is the number of seconds to cache a page. So TIMEOUT is not necessarily useful for all backends.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not sure I understand the distinction. According the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHES-TIMEOUT Timeout is 'The number of seconds before a cache entry is considered stale'. Does that mean the same thing as 'TIMEOUT is the timeout for connecting to the cache backend'?

Comment: You're right my bad. The reference I gave is, in its own words, "extremely out of date."  Since the Django cache provides access to finer granularity than entire pages, I'd guess that is what TIMEOUT is for. CACHE_MIDDLEWARE can only handle entire pages, so you might want different timeouts for that. We'll have to consult the code to be sure.